# What causes these losses in this propeller simulation?

Tags: propeller, blade, flow

While running a CFD simulation comparison of 2 vs 3 blade propeller versions (48" diameter, 23" pitch, 3570RPM), I've come up with:

- 2-blade: 347N of static thrust @ 110Nm Torque
- 3-blade: 220N of static thrust @ 108Nm of Torque

**What is the main destructive force seen in the 3-blade propeller particle flow?**

Are these "not so tippy" blade tip losses, happening even 60% radius?

The number of particles shown is the same, but in the 3-blade version the same particles are being sucked-back into the flow, which explains the drop in the propeller performance.

[image: 2 blade CFD simulation]

[image: 3 blade CFD simulation]

Comment: are the propellers standing still w.r.t. the air mass or is there relative motion?

Comment: It looks like your three blade propeller creates a vortex ring state. What is the forward speed of the propeller w.r.t the undisturbed air mass? It seems the propeller is static.

Comment: It is a static flow simulation with the dynamic airspeed = 0 m/s. Atmospheric conditions are 101325Pa.
I thought Vortex Ring state is only possible with the negative airspeed?

Comment: From the picture it looks like the angle of attack of the 3-blade is much higher than the 2-blade?